# angular : how can i bind select containing date with angular bootstrap calendar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I fill a dropdown list with an array containing objects with a date attribute.
The list is binded on a date variable.
An angular boostrap calendar is binded on this variable.

```
<select id="installFullDate"
    name="installFullDate" 
    class="form-control"
    ng-options="installationSlot.displayDate as installationSlot.displayDate for installationSlot in installationSlots"
    ng-model="user.installation.date"
    required>
</select>
<img class="calendar-datepicker"
    src="images/calendar.png"
    datepicker-popup="mm/dd/yyyy"
    ng-model="user.installation.date"
    is-open="opened"
    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
    date-disabled="disabledDate(date, mode)"
    min-date="minDate"
    max-date="maxDate"
    ng-required="true"
    close-text="X"
    ng-click="open($event)">
<span class="field-description">mm/dd/yyyy</span>
```

The binding works when I select an element in the select, the element is selected in angular boostrap calendar.

When I select the element in the calendar, the date is not selected in the dropdown list.

I think angular can't find the matching object in the dropdown based on the date.
Is angular bootstrap calendar can be bind on a string ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your `installationSlots` array items `displayDate` is a string. To get the binding to work you need to work around a couple of issues.

- The date picker control includes a time if the initial date includes a time (thus clicking Nov 30 will give you a date+time for Nov 30)

  - you can work around this by calling `setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)` on your date before using it to init the date picker
- Two `Date` objects with the same date are not equal: `(new Date(2014, 0, 1) == new Date(2014, 0, 1))` returns false

Based on those issues, using a `Date` object doesn't look like it is going to work.

One solution is to use string comparisons, but how do you keep a string in sync with the `user.installation.date` property?

If you setup a new property using getter/setter that uses the same formatting as your `displayDate` property then you can use string matching for your select list, binding it to the custom property (which under the covers uses the real date), and leave the date picker bound to the real date, e.g.:

### HTML

```
<datepicker ng-model="user.installation.date"></datepicker>
<select ng-model="formattedDate" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"
  ng-options="slot.displayDate as slot.displayDate for slot in installationSlots">
</select>
```

NOTE: that `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"` is very important!

### JavaScript

```
$scope.formattedDate = function(value) {
  if (angular.isDefined(value)) {
    // set
    $scope.user.installation.date = new Date(Date.parse(value));
  }
  return $scope.user.installation.date.toLocaleDateString();
};
```

NOTE: I've used `toLocaleDateString()` for convenience here, but you would need to make sure the formatting is the same as `displayDate`. The [moment JS library](http://momentjs.com) is good for doing date manipulation and formatting.

The return statement above would become something like this:

```
// default to empty string
var result = '';
// moment will use todays date if passed a null or undefined value, don't want that
if (angular.isDefined($scope.user.installation.date)) {
    // format output like "November 30th 2014"
    result = moment($scope.user.installation.date).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
}
return result;
```

Simply adjust the `format()` statement to suit your needs.